# Compare multiple column of dataframe with condition R

Tags: mysql, r, loops, if-statement, matrix

I have a dataframe (containing 200k Rows):

DF1>

```
ID   SR1    SR2      DRC1   DX2
1    123    as#12.c  ABC-1  SXI
2    124    ae&14.v  ABC-1  SXI
3    125    at$19.e  AXX-1    
4    125    at$19.e  AXX-1  SCV
5    785    ab&22.n  AWZ-2  DDF
6    849    ab&22.n  AWZ-5  DDF
```

For this, I want to add new column to `DF1` as `status` based on below conditions all together:

1. Check Every `DX2` Value we have same value in `DRC-1` (i.e For ID 1 and 2 we have same `DRC1` value as `ABC-1`).
2. For some cases i don't have `DX2` Value, for those check `SR-1` and `SR-2` to compare `DRC-1` value throughout the dataframe, if its same show `True` in Status else `False`.

Note: if any value either `SR-1` or `SR-2` Match with any row in the entire dataframe, (i.e. Row No. 4 in desired output)

3. Where we don't have `DX2` Value but when compare through dateframe using `SR-1` and `SR-2`, and found some where we have `DX2` value corresponding to `SR-1` and `SR-2` than give Status as `True-ID` or `False-ID` based on condition.

Desired Output:

```
ID   SR1    SR2      DRC1   DX2  Status
1    123    as#12.c  ABC-1  SXI  True
2    124    ae&14.v  ABC-1  SXI  True
3    125    at$19.e  AXX-1       True-4
4    125    at$19.d  AXX-1  SCV  True
5    785    ab&22.n  AWZ-2  DDF  False
6    849    ab&22.n  AWZ-5  DDF  False
```

So far i could compare only one column with below code:

```
New_DF<-transform(DF_1, Status = ave(as.character(DF_1$DRC1), DF_1$DX2, FUN = function(x) 
  if(length(unique(x)) == 1) "True" else "False" ))
```

**In addition, Just wondering if the same can be done in MySQL.??**

Comment: I believe I saw this question yesterday, under a different username.  What happened to your earlier question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Correct, but that was not structured and unanswered...:(

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you help me here.??

Comment: I don't get your rules. For instance, why does ID 1 get Status TRUE? Isn't its `DX2` different from `DRC1`?

Comment: @ytu ID 1 gets Status TRUE because it's `DX2` value match with ID2's `DX2` value. Suppose we have a row of which all the value are unique to the entire dataframe than it should be true.

Comment: @ytu Pleae provide me answer here.

Comment: You may want to clarify this sentence: “Check Every DX2 Value we have same value in DRC-1” in your post because people tend to interpret as strings in these two columns are the same.

Comment: @www Thanks...corrected it.

Comment: @www Please help me here if you correctly understand my question.

Comment: @akrun please help here.

Comment: @ytu do you clear with rules now.??

Comment: First, how do you "check" `DX2` value when you have same value in `DRC-1`? For instance, what if ID 7 has `DRC-1` as "ABC-1" but its `DX2` is "SXJ"? Is is TRUE or FALSE? Second, "For some cases i don't have `DX2` Value, for those check `SR-1` and `SR-2` to compare `DRC-1` value", but how do you compare them with `DRC-1`? I can hardly interpret your rules. You may need to re-organize your post and clarify your needs before someone can provide answer.

Comment: @ytu For 1 instance if ID 7 has `DRC-1` as "ABC-1" but its `DX2` is "SRJ", it would be FALSE, since for the same `DRC-1` value we have different `DX2` Value. For Instance 2, My sequence of checking would start from `DX2` if i have value in `DX2` column than i check entire dataframe with that only but wherever its blank i check with `SR-1` and `SR-2` value and wherever any of value out of `SR-1` of  `SR-2` match in entire dataframe than my `DRC-1` value should be same as Matched Case for "True" or Status would be "False".

Comment: @ytu Request your help here, since i'm stuck and have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: But why don't ID 1 and 2 get FALSEs and ID 7 gets TRUE? What's your standard? What happened when another "ABC-1" and "SXJ" combination shows up, i.e. two "ABC-1 + SXI"s and two "ABC-1 + SXJ"s?

Comment: For that instance all will be "FALSE", since for Unique ID "ABC-1" we have two different identifier mapped "SXI" and "SXJ".

Comment: @ytu I just want to check that For every Unique `DRC-1` value we have same `DX2` value if available or same `SR-1` or `SR-1` or both `SR-1` and `SR-2` where `DX2` value not available, and for that if we found that for particular row i don't have `DX2` value but when matching with `SR-1` | `SR-2` we found that we have `DX2` where my `SR-1` | `SR-2` match show me status as "True-ID" or "False-ID".

Comment: I am writing my solution. Still I suggest you adding your elaboration here to your original post.

Comment: @ytu Thanks, I just want that for every unique `DRC-1` Value there should be same `DX2` wherever we have `DX2` value, for same `DRC-1` value if we don't have `DX2` value in any row than that row must contain same `SR-1` or `SR-2` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is the best approach or there are more elegant solutions, but it does work for your problem. It could be time-consuming if you have a large dataset though.

```
library(dplyr)

# Create sample data frame
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:6,
  SR1 = c(123,124,125,125,785,849),
  SR2 = c("as#12.c", "ae&14.v", "at$19.e", "at$19.d", "ab&22.n", "ab&22.n"),
  DRC1 = c("ABC-1", "ABC-1", "AXX-1", "AXX-1", "AWZ-2", "AWZ-5"),
  DX2 = c("SXI", "SXI", NA, "SCV", "DDF", "DDF"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Create a function to give Status with each kind of DRC1 according to your rules
StatusJudge <- function(df_sub) {
  if (dim(df_sub)[1] == 1) {
    df_sub$Status <- FALSE
  }
  else {
    if (all(!is.na(df_sub$DX2))) {
      df_sub$Status <-
        ifelse(length(unique(df_sub$DX2)) == 1, TRUE, FALSE)
    }
    else {
      df_sub$Status <-
        ifelse(length(unique(df_sub$SR1)) == 1 | length(unique(df_sub$SR2)) == 1, TRUE, FALSE)
      if (any(!is.na(df_sub$DX2))) {
        df_sub$IDfound[is.na(df_sub$DX2)] <-
          df_sub$ID[!is.na(df_sub$DX2)][1]
      }
    }
  }
  return(df_sub)
}

# Apply the StatusJudge to each element of df_list and then combine the results
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Status = NA, IDfound = NA) %>%
  group_by(DRC1) %>%
  do(StatusJudge(.)) %>%
  arrange(ID)
```

The codes above makes `df`:

```
 ID    SR1     SR2  DRC1   DX2  Status IDfound
<int> <dbl>   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <lgl>   <int>
  1    123   as#12.c ABC-1  SXI   TRUE      NA
  2    124   ae&14.v ABC-1  SXI   TRUE      NA
  3    125   at$19.e AXX-1 <NA>   TRUE       4
  4    125   at$19.d AXX-1  SCV   TRUE      NA
  5    785   ab&22.n AWZ-2  DDF  FALSE      NA
  6    849   ab&22.n AWZ-5  DDF  FALSE      NA
```

I suggest you stopping here because it conserves the nature of logic values, TRUEs and FALSEs, and may be easier for your future analyses, e.g. retrieving rows which have Status as TRUE. That being said, you could paste Status and IDfound together to be the new Status:

```
df$Status <-
  ifelse(!is.na(df$IDfound), paste(df$Status, df$IDfound, sep = "-"), df$Status)
df$IDfound <- NULL
```

, which gives your expected output exactly.

Comment: Its taking too much time to run...:(

Comment: still running, it's been more than 1 hours.

Comment: Please see my edits. It should be much more efficient now.

Comment: I got error:Error in lapply(df_list, StatusJudge) : object 'df_list' not found

Comment: I created `df_list` right after `df$Status <- NA; df$IDfound <- NA`. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes...i did the same.

Comment: Now `df_list <- split(df, df$DRC1)` taking too much time.

Comment: But there shouldn't be an error like yours. I just test my codes on my laptop and they work just fine. The efficient part is trick of `lapply`, which should be much faster than a `for` loop.

Comment: Previously i run whole code, now i am running it line by line and its taking time on  `df_list <- split(df, df$DRC1)` line.

Comment: Please test with my whole code including creating data frame part to validate this method. I am sure there shouldn't be such error even if you run the whole code.

Comment: your code is working fine and giving the desired output, i am first reading around 0.7 million data from csv converting it to dataframe and than running your code.

Comment: I think my data is too large to split using `Split` function.

Comment: Hmm. How about not `split`ing it at all? Try separating them with `group_by`. I've revised my codes and you should be able to see the difference.